# Email enabled document library in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have requirement where users need to send document to SharePoint library by using an email id. please let me know is it possible to achieve. For On premise we can use email enabled libraries but i am not able to find option for SharePoint office 365. What are the alternatives we have in order to achieve this functionality

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online doesn't support incoming emails for document library.

You can try using site mailbox

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-Use-a-site-mailbox-to-collaborate-with-your-team-45fb1ef2-19f5-4bf5-b6e2-8f3f77c09221?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Or use third party tools.